# How to get this fancy editor Wikipedia uses into our own MediaWiki installation

Tags: mediawiki

Really, sorry, if this question seems as if I'd be too lazy to google, but I tried to find that out myself and failed:

What's the name of the extension for MediaWiki or whatever would I have to use to get this nice and fancy editor that Wikipedia uses into my own MediaWiki installation?

I already use the newest MediaWiki version (1.17.0) but still have these ugly and pretty useless buttons on top of my edit pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a list of and source code for all the MediaWiki extensions used by Wikipedia here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Version

[WikiEditor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aUsabilityInitiative) is probably the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The version of MediaWiki used by Wikipedia is 1.17wmf1, which I'm guessing stands for Wikimedia Foundation. They use a customised version of the software for their own purposes. I think all you can do is hope they include that new editor in a future release. Or else you could try and download the scripts that they're using and reverse engineer the pages, but that may break the license agreement.

Comment: Alright, thanks Paul. At least I know now that I was not just too stupid to figure out how to do it. I'd like to vote your answer up but the system tells me I'd have to have a better reputation to do it...

Comment: @Moritz You might be able to tick the answer though.